# What distance do I use when examining the effect of an electric field on a point outside of a nonconducting sphere with an arbitrary volume charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

It's easy enough for me to do this for a ring (as I interpret the field lines as "exiting from the centre of the ring") or a point (simply the distance from the point to the other point), but I just realised that, with a volume-charged (nonconducting) sphere, I have no idea what kind of distance I'm meant to put.

Do I use the distance of each elementary charge of the ball (thus probably complicating the integration to all hell)? Do I use the distance to the centre of the sphere, as it's done with gravity? I'd like to know which one of these is the correct one, and I'd really appreciate it if somebody could explain *why* it's the correct choice so I can understand what I'm doing in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: If the charge distribution is uniform, then we can assume it as a point charge with magnitude of total charge.

Comment: If charge distribution is proportional to radius then integrate the shells which are acting like point charges.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a generic volume charge $\rho(x, y, z)$, each "small piece" of the charge object generates an electric field at a generic point $\vec{P}$ is given by

$$
d\vec{E} =\frac{\rho(x, y, z) \hat{r}}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}
$$

where $\hat{r} = \vec{r}/r$, $\vec{r}$ is the vector joining $(x, y, z)$ and $\vec{P}$ and $r$ is its module. *This* distance is well defined. The "full" electric field is given by the sum of all these contributions, which is computed by taking an integral over the volume $V$ of the charged object:

$$
\vec{E} = \int_V\frac{\rho(x, y, z) \hat{r} dx dy dz}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}
$$

where both $r$ and $\hat{r}$ depends on $x, y, z$.